# Python: how to subscript 2D array using two 1D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am very new to Python, but I have experience with Matlab.

In my code I want to subscript 2D array using two 1D arrays as follows:

```
a=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
patch=np.arange(2)
b = a [patch]
c= a[patch] [patch]
```

As a result, I want to have a 2x2 matrix: `[(1, 2) (4, 5)]`. Instead, my `b` and `c` are 2x3 matrices: `b=c=[(1, 2, 3), (4,5,6)]`

I was not able to solve it by myself. I know, that `a[0:2,0:2]` works, but in my code, I want to do it using predefined 1D arrays.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure about : `[(1, 2) (4, 6)]`?

Comment: What's with the 6?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the question